# Automate scp website file transfer using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh, ubuntu-14.04, scp

i have 3 digital ocean droplets, how to automate one droplet files to another 2 droplets, so i was write a scp shell script. 
guys do you have any other suggestions or easily file transfer between two droplets?

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Variables
SERVER1USER=root
SERVER1PSWD=killergirls
SERVER1IP=123.123.123.123
SERVER1PATH=/etc/var/html/www/

SERVER2USER=root
SERVER2PSWD=killerboys
SERVER2IP=121.121.121.121
SERVER2PATH=/etc/var/html/www/

echo -e "\n--- First Server files transferring now... ---\n"
sshpass -p "$SERVER1PSWD" scp -r /etc/var/html/www/ SERVER1USER@SERVER1IP:$SERVER1PATH

echo -e "\n--- Second Server files transferring now... ---\n"
sshpass -p "$SERVER2PSWD" scp -r /etc/var/html/www/ SERVER2USER@SERVER2IP:$SERVER2PATH
```

Comment: What is the problem you need help with?

Comment: what you have seems completely usable. But it's always a good habit to dbl-quote all variable names , so `scp -r /etc/var/html/www/ SERVER1USER@SERVER1IP:"$SERVER1PATH"` etc will save you in the future when you have a path with spaces in a directory name. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to program things like this in python. Below I have a sample of one script that I use to deploy hadoop to a cluster.
It can be expanded easily by adding more files, commands, or ips.

Note that I like being able to print everything that is going to be executed before I actually run it.
This is done with the DEBUG variable.

Also note, this can be accomplished in bash, but since I am not an accomplished Bash programmer, Python is much easier and less error prone for me.

```py
DEBUG=1
import subprocess
call = subprocess.call
ips = []
for i in range(0,10):
    ips.append("10.0.0.%d"%(i))
commands = 'ls; echo "Hello"'
def hadoop_setup(ip):
        sshTemplate = "ssh hdfs@%s '%s;'"
        for eachCommand in commands.split(";"):
                sshCall = sshTemplate%(ip, eachCommand)
                if DEBUG: print sshCall
                else: call(sshCall, shell=True)


copyFileTemplate = 'scp %s hdfs@%s:/home/hdfs'
for file in ['.bashrc']:
    for ip in ips:
        copyFileCall = copyFileTemplate%(file,ip)
        call(copyFileCall, shell=True)
```